# Twitter Sentiments Analysis useful features

Tags: nlp, text-processing, classification, sentiment-analysis

I'm trying to implement Sentiments Analysis functionality and looking for useful features which can be extracted from tweet messages.The features which I have in my mind for now are:

1. Sentiment words
2. Emotion icons
3. Exclamation marks
4. Negation words
5. Intensity words(very,really etc)

Is there any other useful features for this task?
My goal is not only detect that tweet is positive or negative but also I need to detect level of positivity or negativity(let say in a scale from 0 to 100).
Any inputs or references to printed papers are very welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Others that may be useful are:

- elongated words (eg. goooood)
- unigrams and bigrams of every word (particularly if you have a large corpus)

Regarding references: 
This tutorial by Christopher Potts is very good and to the point: http://sentiment.christopherpotts.net/

Other papers:

- Twitter as a Corpus for Sentiment Analysis and Opinion Mining.
  Alexander Pak, Patrick Paroubek
- Twitter Sentiment Classification using Distant Supervision. Go et al. 2009.
- Robust Sentiment Detection on Twitter from Biased and Noisy Data. Barbosa and Feng. 2010.
- Sentiment strength detection in short informal text. Thelwall et al.
  (2010). JAIST

Answer (score 2):

If I post really good news on twitter, a lot of people might start publicly congratulating me.
So If I post X, and then get a lot of 'Congrats' tweets from other people, then X is probably positive.
In general, the type and frequency of people who retweet my tweet might have something to do with its inherent sentiment.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following articles:

- Belgian elections, June 13, 2010 - Twitter opinion mining, http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-examples-elections
- 100 days of web mining, http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-examples-100days